# Installing Linux Kernel Modules

Tags: linux-kernel

I usually only work on the FreeBSD kernel and it is a bit different.  I get up to the stage of making and installing the modules, but how do you actually boot the kernel that you just built?

Comment: How can kernel programing be a question on superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your system is configured, but you want to copy the bzImage file somewhere your boot loader can see it, then update configs (if necessary).  On my gentoo box:

`#pwd is /usr/src/linux

cp arch/i386/boot/bzImage /boot/default-kernel`

Comment: so I configured and built my kernel in ~/kern, so the image would end up in /arch   ?

Comment: Assuming it's like mine, ~/kern/arch/i386/boot/bzImage.  Check documentation for your distro.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look [here](http://www.cromwell-intl.com/unix/linux-kernel.html). Essentially it's something along the lines of `make menuconfig`, `make all`, `make install`, `make install_modules`, `make install_firmware`, and then tweaks in grub or lilo config.